Google one tap signin works on development but doesn't work in production after signed by Google App Signing
I have a Flutter app with Google One Tap signin.
The functionality works on emulator and real device when being distributed in debug mode however after uploading to the Play console and downloading on real device it does not.
I have added the upload certificate SHA-1, debug SHA-1 and Google App Signing SHA-1 to Firebase console, downloaded the google-services.json, rebuilt the app and reuploaded it to the Play Store.
What am I missing?
The exception I get on the real device:
2024-04-18 11:04:16.192 13966-9031/? W/Auth.Api.Credentials: [CompleteSignInOperation] Operation failed. [CONTEXT service_id=179 ]
dvhj: dvhj: bdgh: Developer console is not set up correctly
at bdkt.apply(:com.google.android.gms@241217031@24.12.17 (150400-623887440):43)
at dvdd.d(:com.google.android.gms@241217031@24.12.17 (150400-623887440):3)
at dvde.run(:com.google.android.gms@241217031@24.12.17 (150400-623887440):130)
at alad.c(:com.google.android.gms@241217031@24.12.17 (150400-623887440):50)
at alad.run(:com.google.android.gms@241217031@24.12.17 (150400-623887440):76)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at alft.run(:com.google.android.gms@241217031@24.12.17 (150400-623887440):8)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
Caused by: dvhj: bdgh: Developer console is not set up correctly
at bdkj.apply(:com.google.android.gms@241217031@24.12.17 (150400-623887440):11)
at dvdk.d(:com.google.android.gms@241217031@24.12.17 (150400-623887440):3)
The firebase console:

The Google App signing public SHA-1 and upload SHA-1:

Signing report of the App bundle:

I've tried everything that I found in the documentation and publicly on Stackoverflow.
